# Few days in and looking for efficiency advice

Tags: java

Im a few days into learning Java (My first language) and im just wondering if there is a more efficient way of writing this code?

Main goal of the program is to calculate someones BMI.

It asks a user for their name, asks if they'd like to use Metric or Imperial, asks for the measurements and provides the answer with a small chart for the user to see where they fit.

It works fine at the moment but im trying to figure out ways to condense the code and make it more efficient (purely for learning purposes)

```
    import java.util.Scanner; //importing the java library utilities to use the scan functions

        public class Bmi0 //declaring my intitial class and making it a public class
        {
            public static void main(String[] args) //my main method 
            {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // starts the scanner utility to take input fromm the command line

                float height; //declaring a variable
                float weight; //declaring a variable
                float bmi; //declaring a variable
                String option; //declaring a variable
                String name; //declaration of a variable called name of type string


                System.out.printf("%nWhat is your name? ");//prompts the user for their name
                name = input.nextLine(); //reads the users input and saves it to the variable name

                System.out.printf("%nHi %s, Let's calculate you BMI %n" , name); //displays what the user 
                //typed using a %s as the place holder for the value that is in the name variable


                System.out.printf("%nUse Imperial or Metric? (Format: I or M) "); //printing to the command window and asking for input
                option = input.nextLine(); //placing the user input into the height variable

                if (option.equals ("M")) //if option is M for metric do the following
                {

                System.out.printf("%nWhat is your height in Meters? "); //printing to the command window and asking for input
                height = input.nextFloat(); //placing the user input into the height variable

                System.out.print("What is your weight in Kilos? "); //printing to the command window and asking for input
                weight = input.nextFloat(); //placing the user input into the weight variable

                bmi = (weight / (height * height)); //calculates  the conversion and stores it in the variable


                System.out.printf("%nOk %s, your BMI is: %.2f%n%n" , name, bmi); //displays the answer to 2 decimal places
                System.out.printf("BMI Categories:%n Underweight = <18.5 %n Normal weight = 18.5 - 24.9 %n Overweight = 25 - 29.9 %n Obesity = BMI of 30 or greater %n%n%n");
                }

                else if (option.equals ("I")) //if the imperial option is chosen
                {

                System.out.printf("%nWhat is your height in Inches? "); //printing to the command window and asking for input
                height = input.nextFloat(); //placing the user input into the height variable

                System.out.printf("What is your weight in Pounds? "); //printing to the command window and asking for input
                weight = input.nextFloat(); //placing the user input into the weight variable

                bmi = (weight / (height * height) * 703) ; //calculates  the conversion and stores it in the variable


                System.out.printf("%nOk %s, your BMI is: %.2f%n%n" , name, bmi); //displays the answer to 2 decimal places
                System.out.printf("BMI Categories:%n Underweight = <18.5 %n Normal weight = 18.5 - 24.9 %n Overweight = 25 - 29.9 %n Obesity = BMI of 30 or greater %n%n%n");
                }

                } //end of the method
    }//end of the class
```

Comment: This may be more on-topic at the Code Review site: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank You, I'll look at that now.

Comment: doesn't matter what language you use, always free resources when you finish interacting, in this case, you have to close your Scanner. Next, store only the data that is necessary, you don't have to save bmi in this case, if you're not going to be using it further. You haven't handled exceptions here, what if the users type  `m` instead of `M`. (use EqualsIgnoreCase) or maybe they enter some other value, handling exceptions is important. Using println instead of printf is preferred

Comment: Thank you kowsikbabu for the advice, as i said im only a few days (actually about 6hours) into learning my first language, this is the third program i have ever written, I dont know how to handle exceptions in the program yet or how to close out the Scanner and free resources. I'm aware of their importance, at this moment in time I have barely learned past the basic "hello world", I will get there soon though hopefully. Thanks again for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- too many comments. `//importing the java library utilities to use the scan functions` ... that doesn't tell the reader anything that `import java.util.Scanner` doesn't already give away. **Too** much information in code is counter productive. It makes the reader waste his time and energy on details that don't matter. Instead: write your code in ways that make its intention clear, *without* the need of extensive comments.
- formatting: follow the standard java coding style guides. Like: keep the opening `{` on the line of the if condition for example. Do **not** add another empty line after the brace. Instead, **indent** the new block with 2 or 4 spaces. One pretty famous approach right now is the one from [google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

Your code is "okay" for a new newbie, but as said: most of the comments could be thrown out, and that would *improve* readability. The next improvement would be to put the different "aspects" into smaller helper methods, to avoid having everything in one lengthy main method.

Comment: @Zap-Brannigan For the record: I updated my answer and added a link to the google java styleguide. Good read!

Comment: @zap-brannigan Side note, you can set up your IDE to automatically format your code for you. This will fix indents/brace issues.

Comment: Very much appreciated.